# How to use the 'overrides' folder generated by Sencha cmd for an Ext JS 4 project

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have generated a project using Sencha cmd. This creates a nice folder named 'overrides' where I have put my overridden Ext.Ajax class. I then include it in my app.js file like so

```
requires: [
    'overrides.Ajax'
]
```

This works just fine when using my app, however when I try to build it using Sencha cmd I get the following error:

```
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurred while e
xecuting this line:
[ERR] Z:\public_html\LoginScreen\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:469: com.sencha.exce
ptions.ExBuild: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for Z:\p
ublic_html\LoginScreen\app\app.js::ClassRequire::overrides.Ajax
```

Does anyone know how to properly include files that are inside the overrides folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I needed to edit the .sencha/app/sencha.cfg file, adding the following to the end of the app.classpath

```
,${app.dir}/overrides
```

Thanks to Mitchell over at the official Sencha forums for helping me out!
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?261361-Properly-using-the-overrides-folder-generated-by-Sencha-Cmd-for-Ext-Js-4.2

Answer (score 4):

For Ext 5 user, you can specify "overrides folder" in app.json. Example:

```
"overrides": "${app.dir}/overrides",
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me. I don't know why they're ignoring "app.classpath" property in sencha.cfg file.

Comment: In Ext 6 the default value is missing the "${app.dir}" value

Answer (score 1):

You probably need path defined in your loader config for overrides.

Something like this:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    paths: {
        'Ext.ux': 'js/extjs/ux',
        'overrides' : 'somepath/to/overrides',
        'Skirtle.CTemplate':'js/extjs/ux/SkirtleCTemplate.js' //<-- specific component
    }
});
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but it does not seem to by my problem. Since the 'overrides' folder appears next to 'app' and 'ext' I added 'overrides':'overrides' to my path but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

For me just the

```
requires: [
    'overrides.Ajax'
]
```

didn't work I had to add

```
requires: [
    'MyApp.overrides.Ajax'
]
```

And it worked :)

Also the vars

```
// @require @packageOverrides
// @require @appOverrides
```

don't do anything for me, so the steps are

1. add the `,${app.dir}/overrides` in the `sencha.cfg`
2. add the requires in the `app.js` inside the `Ext.application`

Tested in `Sencha Cmd v4.0.2.67`