# override Ajax.js with listener for requestexception not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

This is included in a requires statement in the main app. It loads Ajax then dies. I'm using
Extjs 5. The code is in an overrides  folder under ui/. It can't seem to find the code in a folder at the same level as app.

```
Ext.define('Ext.overrides.Ajax', {
    override : 'Ext.data.Connection',
    listeners : {
        requestexception : function(response) {

        var error = response.status + ' - ' + response.statusText;
        // if response status is 202 (Accepted), should
        // have warning message
        if (response.status == 202) {
            Ext.Msg.show({
                title : 'REST Warning message',
                msg : 'Ajax Request Exception! ' + error,
                cls : 'msg-wrap',
                buttons : Ext.Msg.OK,
                icon : Ext.Msg.WARNING
            });
        }

        if (response.status > 400) {
            var errorData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);

            Ext.Msg.show({
                title : 'REST Error message',
                msg : 'Ajax Request Exception! ' + errorData,
                cls : 'msg-wrap',
                buttons : Ext.Msg.OK,
                icon : Ext.Msg.ERROR
            });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. In ExtJS 4, I had a Ext.Ajax override configured just like yours.

To get it to work with ExtJS 5, I read http://www.sencha.com/blog/top-support-tips-october-2014 and successfully changed my override structure to the following:

```
 Ext.define('Ext.override.AjaxOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.Ajax'
    // omitted overridden properties...

}, function() {
    var me = this;

    me.setExtraParams({
        foo: "bar" 
    });

    me.setUrl('MyUrl');
    me.setTimeout(600000);

    me.on({
        scope: me,
        requestexception: function(conn, response, opts) {
            // my exception handling
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This works for me. [Here is a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023619/how-to-use-the-overrides-folder-generated-by-sencha-cmd-for-an-ext-js-4-projec) explaining how to configure the `override` folder. Thanks!