# Assigning a default function to an Ext.Ajax.request failure

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs5

I make a ton of ajax requests in my application using `Ext.Ajax.request`.  A lot of times I don't want or have the time to put in any fancy error handling if the request fails, so I end up doing something like this:

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'requesturl',
        success: function (response) {
            //request successful. do stuff with response
        },
        failure: function () {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Unknown Error', 'Please alert an administrator.');
        }
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can define a default Ajax request failure function so I don't have to include the failure parameter on every Ajax request I write.

Comment: Which version are you using? Are you using MVC? MVVM?

Comment: This is a cheap way out, not very user friendly. You should write error messages that are context sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create your own custom method on `Ext.Ajax` that has a default failure handler. In this example I just mocked up the `Ext` object for simplicity.

```js
//Placeholder for the actual Ext object for the purposes of demonstration
var Ext = {
  Ajax: {
    request: function (r) {
      //Simulate a failure
      r.failure();
    }
  },
  Msg: {
    alert: function (title, message) {
      var el = document.createElement('div');
      
      el.innerHTML = title + ' - ' + message;
      document.body.appendChild(el);
    }
  }
}

//Add a custom method to Ext.Ajax
Ext.Ajax.requestWithDefaultFailure = function (r) {
  r.failure || (r.failure = function () {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Unknown Error', 'Please alert an administrator.');
  });
  
  Ext.Ajax.request(r);
};

//Now make your calls with the new method
Ext.Ajax.requestWithDefaultFailure({
  url: 'requesturl',
  success: function (response) {
    //request successful. do stuff with response
  }
});

Ext.Ajax.requestWithDefaultFailure({
  url: 'anotherUrl',
  success: function (response) {
    //request successful. do stuff with response
  },
  failure: function () {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'I specified a failure handler, so make sure to use that one instead of the default.')
  }
});
```

Or, if you want to leave `Ext` untouched, you could define your own module for helper methods and use that:

```
var ExtHelpers = {  
  ajaxRequestWithDefaultFailure: function (r) {
    r.failure || (r.failure = function () {
      Ext.Msg.alert('Unknown Error', 'Please alert an administrator.');
    });

    Ext.Ajax.request(r);
  };
};
```

Comment: Why not an override? Or extend the ajax class? And where would you put this code?

Comment: @Tarabass If by override you mean replace the default `Ajax.request` method, that seems like a bad idea to me, as the default functionality is lost if that is needed elsewhere. As for where the code should be placed, that would depend entirely on the structure of OP's project. I imagine it could be placed in a module near wherever the ext.js files themselves are referenced.

Comment: You should install the failure handler only if one is not provided.

Comment: @JuanMendes Good point, I updated the answer to check for an existing handler.

Comment: @DrewGaynor Everyone is overriding and extending their ass off, because that's the power of the class system of ExtJs using MVC. It's even recommended. The question was to put a failure from one place on every ajax request, and even then you can set failure like Juan mentioned.

Comment: @Tarabass Overrides are not really recommended, you are usually messing with internals. Yes, I know they are often needed, but recommended is too strong, overrides always give us a hard time when upgrading...

Comment: @JuanMendes It's very true what you are saying. Good to point that out.

Answer (score 2):

A less intrusive way is to install a global handler. It would have the problem mentioned by Drew, every call would be affected. So it would be simpler to change existing code, if you really want that behavior for all Ext.Ajax.request calls. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-event-beforerequest

```
Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function( conn, options, eOpts ) {
    if (!options.failure) {
        options.failure = function() {...} 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

All roads lead to Rome. But I think the most graceful way is using "Ext.app.EventDomain".

```js
// connect Ext.Ajax enent to Bus
Ext.define('MyApp.domain.Ajax', {
 extend: 'Ext.app.EventDomain',
 singleton: true,
 type: 'extAjax',
 idProperty: 'myRequest',
 constructor: function() {
  var me = this;
  me.callParent();
  me.monitor(Ext.Ajax);
 }
});

Ext.define('Myapp.controller.Workspace', {
 extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

 init: function() {
  var me = this;
  // use this controller to deal with event from Ext.ajax
  me.listen({
   extAjax: {
    '*': {

     requestexception: function(conn, response, options) {
      console.log('exception', response.status, response);
      if (response.status == 403) {
       // open a window to ask login
       popLoginWin();
      }
     }
    }
   }
  });
 }
});
```

I use this way to process Session expired, while it certainly can deal with other situations.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [`override`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972640/override-ajax-js-with-listener-for-requestexception-not-working) to accomplish this, or create you own ajax class and `extend` from `Ext.ajax` when using `MVC`. From there you can implement some decent error handling and/or logging.

In ExtJs 4

```
Ext.define('Ext.overrides.Ajax', {
    override : 'Ext.data.Connection',
    listeners : {
        requestexception : function(response) {
            var error = response.status + ' - ' + response.statusText;
            // if response status is 202 (Accepted), should
            // have warning message
            if (response.status == 202) {
                Ext.Msg.show({
                    title : 'REST Warning message',
                    msg : 'Ajax Request Exception! ' + error,
                    cls : 'msg-wrap',
                    buttons : Ext.Msg.OK,
                    icon : Ext.Msg.WARNING
                });
            }

            if (response.status > 400) {
                var errorData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);

                Ext.Msg.show({
                    title : 'REST Error message',
                    msg : 'Ajax Request Exception! ' + errorData,
                    cls : 'msg-wrap',
                    buttons : Ext.Msg.OK,
                    icon : Ext.Msg.ERROR
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In ExtJs 5

```
Ext.define('Ext.override.AjaxOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.Ajax'
    // omitted overridden properties...

}, function() {
    var me = this;

    me.setExtraParams({
        foo: "bar" 
    });

    me.setUrl('MyUrl');
    me.setTimeout(600000);

    me.on({
        scope: me,
        requestexception : function(response) {
            var error = response.status + ' - ' + response.statusText;
            // if response status is 202 (Accepted), should
            // have warning message
            if (response.status == 202) {
                Ext.Msg.show({
                    title : 'REST Warning message',
                    msg : 'Ajax Request Exception! ' + error,
                    cls : 'msg-wrap',
                    buttons : Ext.Msg.OK,
                    icon : Ext.Msg.WARNING
                });
            }

            if (response.status > 400) {
                var errorData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);

                Ext.Msg.show({
                    title : 'REST Error message',
                    msg : 'Ajax Request Exception! ' + errorData,
                    cls : 'msg-wrap',
                    buttons : Ext.Msg.OK,
                    icon : Ext.Msg.ERROR
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Or extend (even better) from `Ext.ajax` with something like this

```
Ext.define('APP.ux.Ajax', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Connection',

    requires: [
        'APP.ux.Msg'
    ],

    singleton : true,
    autoAbort : false,

    request: function(config) {
        var cfg = config;

        Ext.apply(cfg, {
            success: function(form, action) {
                APP.ux.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
                //TODO: Add more logic here
            },
            failure: function(form, action) {
                switch (action.failureType) {
                    case Ext.form.action.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
                        APP.ux.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Form fields may not be submitted with invalid values');
                        break;
                    case Ext.form.action.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
                        APP.ux.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Ajax communication failed');
                        break;
                    case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID:
                        APP.ux.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        this.callParent(cfg);
    }
});
```